# Is this escape unescape function pair correct?

Tags: python, escaping

Is this example of an escape - unescape function correct?

```
ESCAPE = '/'

def escape(s):
    rv = s
    rv = rv.replace(ESCAPE, ESCAPE + ESCAPE)
    rv = rv.replace('+', ESCAPE + 'PLUS')
    rv = rv.replace('-', ESCAPE + 'MINUS')
    return rv

def unescape(s):
    rv = s
    rv = rv.replace(ESCAPE + 'MINUS', '-')
    rv = rv.replace(ESCAPE + 'PLUS', '+')
    rv = rv.replace(ESCAPE + ESCAPE, ESCAPE)
    return rv
```

Comment: Is this from your own code, or is it purely an example?  The latter is off-topic.

Comment: Own code, however simplified function, just looking for confirmation on the exact sequence of replacements.

Comment: Write a test to see. Try this: unescape("//+") and see what you get.

Comment: I wrote tests, I think it's ok. @Kylar I'm not sure if the unescape function should except the + sign to unescape...

Comment: Exactly my point. Escaping/Unescaping is tricky. You may want to iterate through the string by yourself, and keep a state machine. It will make things much easier when you hit unexpected data.

Comment: @Kylar thanks for the pointer to state machine approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performing string substitutions using multiple passes is almost always a bad idea, not only for performance, but for correctness.  In this case, there is indeed a bug: `unescape('//PLUS/PLUS')` should produce `'/PLUS+'`, but instead produces `'/++'`.

Therefore, you have to parse the input string in one pass:

```
import re

def unescape(s):
    def replacement(match):
        return {
            '/': '/',
            'PLUS': '+',
            'MINUS': '-',
        }[match.group(1)]
    return re.sub('/(/|PLUS|MINUS)', replacement, s)
```

In your original code and in the implementation above, there is a lot of repetition.  If there are more symbols being escaped than just `+` and `-`, then it makes sense to specify the mapping just once.

```
ESCAPE_CHAR = '/'
ESCAPE = {
    ESCAPE_CHAR: ESCAPE_CHAR,
    '+': 'PLUS',
    '-': 'MINUS',
}
ESCAPE_RE = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, ESCAPE.keys())))

UNESCAPE = dict((v, k) for (k, v) in ESCAPE.items())
UNESCAPE_RE = re.compile(
    re.escape(ESCAPE_CHAR) + '(' +
        '|'.join(map(re.escape, UNESCAPE.keys())) +
    ')')

def escape(s):
    return ESCAPE_RE.sub(lambda match: ESCAPE_CHAR + ESCAPE[match.group(0)], s)

def unescape(s):
    return UNESCAPE_RE.sub(lambda match: UNESCAPE[match.group(1)], s)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me so clearly that multiple passes is indeed a bad idea.

Comment: I never realized that working from left to right is so important in escape functions.