# Fastest possible text template for repeated use?

Tags: java, regex, template, rags-to-riches, compiler

While [reviewing Sending templatized e-mail to a million contacts](/a/102340/9357), I wrote this implementation to illustrate an alternate approach.  It is designed to be the fastest possible way to generate templated text repeatedly.  Is it?

I used the in-memory Java compiler featured in [this Stack Overflow answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/28890356/1157100).

I think that the `stringLiteral()` function and the try-catch block that performs the compilation are rather ugly.

### Template.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Map;

public interface Template {
    public void write(Writer out, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException;
}
```

### TemplateCompiler.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.tools.*;
import org.mdkt.compiler.InMemoryJavaCompiler;

public class TemplateCompiler {
    private static final Pattern SUBST_PAT = Pattern.compile(
        "(?<LITERAL>.*?)(?:\\{\\{(?<SUBST>[^}]*)\\}\\})"
    );

    /**
     * Instantiates a <code>Template</code> that performs simple
     * text substitutions for <code>{{PLACEHOLDERS}}</code>.
     */
    public static Template compile(String templateText) {
        int rest = 0;
        StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder(
            "import java.io.IOException;\n" +
            "import java.io.Writer;\n" +
            "import java.util.Map;\n" +
            "public class C implements Template {\n" +
            "    public void write(Writer out, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {\n"
        );
        for (Matcher m = SUBST_PAT.matcher(templateText); m.find(); rest = m.end()) {
            script.append("out.write(")
                  .append(stringLiteral(m.group("LITERAL")))
                  .append(");\nout.write(params.get(")
                  .append(stringLiteral(m.group("SUBST")))
                  .append("));\n");
        }
        script.append("out.write(")
              .append(stringLiteral(templateText.substring(rest)))
              .append(");\n");

        script.append("out.flush();\n")
              .append("}}");

        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Class <? extends Template> c = (Class <? extends Template>)InMemoryJavaCompiler.compile("C", script.toString());
            Constructor<? extends Template> ctr = c.getConstructor();
            return ctr.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static final Pattern UNSAFE_CHARS = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]");

    private static String stringLiteral(String s) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("\"");
        Matcher matcher = UNSAFE_CHARS.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            char c = matcher.group().charAt(0);
            switch (c) {
              // JLS SE7 3.10.5: 
              // It is a compile-time error for a line terminator to appear
              case '\r':
                matcher.appendReplacement(result, "\\r");
                break;
              case '\n':
                matcher.appendReplacement(result, "\\n");
                break;
              default:
                String.format("\\\\u%04x", (int)c);
            }
        }
        matcher.appendTail(result);
        result.append("\"");
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

### Sample usage

> ```
> Template t = TemplateCompiler.compile(
>     "Dear {{USER_NAME}},\n\n" +
>     "According to our records, your phone number is {{USER_PHONE}} and " +
>     "your e-mail address is {{USER_EMAIL}}.  If this is incorrect, please " +
>     "go to {{LOGIN_URL}} and update your contact information."
> );
> for (Contact c : contacts) {
>     Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
>     params.put("USER_NAME", c.getUserName());
>     params.put("USER_EMAIL", c.getEmail());
>     params.put("USER_PHONE", c.getPhone());
>     params.put("LOGIN_URL", c.getLoginUrl());
>     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
>     t.write(sw, params);
>     sw.toString();
> }
> ```

Comment: Just a comment because it is not part of your code: One thing about templatized E-mails that I see fairly often is that some replacement marker was not replaced appropriately. Maybe you should add a check if all `{{}}` have been set/replaced. One step further would be to test whether there are some malformed instances like `{{}`. On an easier level this could be checked with a (unit)test dataset against your expectation which could even have caught the errors @rofl reported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compile concept produced incorrect results for me. When I run your code the template does not produce the correct results. For the input parameters:

```
final Map<String,String> parms = new HashMap<>();
Stream.of("USER_NAME", "USER_PHONE", "USER_EMAIL", "LOGIN_URL")
      .forEach(tag -> parms.put(tag, tag));
```

I would expect the input String:

> ```
> "Dear {{USER_NAME}},\n\n" +
> "According to our records, your phone number is {{USER_PHONE}} and " +
> "your e-mail address is {{USER_EMAIL}}.  If this is incorrect, please " +
> "go to {{LOGIN_URL}} and update your contact information."
> ```

to produce:

> ```
> Dear USER_NAME,
>
> According to our records, your phone number is USER_PHONE and your e-mail address is USER_EMAIL.  If this is incorrect, please go to LOGIN_URL and update your contact information.
> ```

But, instead, it produces:

> ```
> Dear USER_NAMEAccording to our records, your phone number is USER_PHONE and your e-mail address is USER_EMAIL.  If this is incorrect, please go to LOGIN_URL and update your contact information.
> ```

I have looked through the code, and I am not sure why it is dropping the newlines, and the comma-punctuation after "USER_NAME".

I looked through the TemplateCompile code, and while I like that you use a Pattern/Matcher to parse the template, the actual loop structure is really complicated. You shoe-horn the process in to a for-loop, when a while-loop would be much better. Additionally, you use a complicated double-matching named-group regular expression, when a single-matching one would be more than adequate.

I particularly dislike the `rest` variable, and how it is used.

I wonder if this complicated regex logic is the cause of the broken output?

I wrote a "competing" code block, and I also chose regex to parse the template, but my loop is very different:

```
private static final Pattern token = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(\\w+)\\}\\}");

public static Template compile(String text) {

    Matcher mat = token.matcher(text);

    int last = 0;

    while (mat.find()) {
        // the non-token text is from the last match end,
        // to this match start
        final String constant = text.substring(last, mat.start());
        // this token's key is the regex group
        final String key = mat.group(1);

        // do stuff with the text and subsequent token
        ....

        last = mat.end();
    }
    final String tail = text.substring(last);
    if (!tail.isEmpty()) {
        // do something with trailing text after last token.
        ....
    }

}
```

A while loop on the `Matcher.find()` result is the natural loop constraint.

Instead of compiling the code down, I used an array of text injectors to perform the write. Some injectors inject a constant value, others inject a lookup value from the Parameters. I was able to reduce your class down to much simpler constructs, with no code abstraction and compilation, etc. From a readability and maintenance perspective I believe it is clearly better:

```
public class MonkeyFix implements Template {

    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface Injector {
        String get(Map<String,String> params);
    }

    private static final Pattern token = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(\\w+)\\}\\}");

    public static Template compile(final String text) {
        final Matcher mat = token.matcher(text);
        final List<Injector> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
        int last = 0;

        while (mat.find()) {
            final String constant = text.substring(last, mat.start());
            final String key = mat.group(1);

            sequence.add(params -> constant);
            sequence.add(params -> params.get(key));

            last = mat.end();
        }

        final String tail = text.substring(last);
        if (!tail.isEmpty()) {
            sequence.add(params -> tail);
        }

        return new MonkeyFix(sequence.toArray(new Injector[sequence.size()]));
    }

    private final Injector[] sequence;

    public MonkeyFix(Injector[] sequence) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Writer out, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
        for (Injector lu : sequence) {
            out.write(lu.get(params));
        }
    }

}
```

How about the performance, though?

I pout the code through my MicroBench suite, using the following code (I had to use a different validation string for your code, I called that one `wrong` ... ;-) :

```
public class TemplateMain {

    private static final String text = 
            "Dear {{USER_NAME}},\n\n" +
            "According to our records, your phone number is {{USER_PHONE}} and " +
            "your e-mail address is {{USER_EMAIL}}.  If this is incorrect, please " +
            "go to {{LOGIN_URL}} and update your contact information.";

    private static final Template inmemcomp = TemplateCompiler.compile(text);

    private static final Template monkeyfix = MonkeyFix.compile(text);

    private static final String inMemFunc(Template t, Map<String, String> params) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        try {
            t.write(sw, params);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sw.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UUtils.setStandaloneLogging(Level.INFO);
        UBench bench = new UBench("Templating");
        final String expect = "Dear USER_NAME,\n\n" +
                "According to our records, your phone number is USER_PHONE and " +
                "your e-mail address is USER_EMAIL.  If this is incorrect, please " +
                "go to LOGIN_URL and update your contact information.";
        final String wrong = "Dear USER_NAMEAccording to our records, your phone number is USER_PHONE and your e-mail address is USER_EMAIL.  If this is incorrect, please go to LOGIN_URL and update your contact information.";

        System.out.println(expect);
        System.out.println(wrong);

        final Map<String,String> parms = new HashMap<>();
        Stream.of("USER_NAME", "USER_PHONE", "USER_EMAIL", "LOGIN_URL").forEach(tag -> parms.put(tag, tag));

        bench.addTask("InMemCompile", () -> inMemFunc(inmemcomp, parms), got -> wrong.equals(got));
        bench.addTask("MonkeyFix", () -> inMemFunc(monkeyfix, parms), got -> expect.equals(got));

        bench.press(10000).report();

    }
}
```

The results are inconclusive on my computer, sometimes your code wins, sometimes mine does. Regardless, they are both "fast enough", and the differences are marginal.

Answer (score 3):

@rolfl has uncovered some embarrassing bugs in the output.

Parts of the literal strings were being dropped due to a missing `Pattern.DOTALL` flag:

```
private static final Pattern SUBST_PAT = Pattern.compile(
    "(?<LITERAL>.*?)(?:\\{\\{(?<SUBST>[^}]*)\\}\\})", Pattern.DOTALL
);
```

In `stringLiteral()`, all three cases were wrong:

```
        switch (c) {
          // JLS SE7 3.10.5: 
          // It is a compile-time error for a line terminator to appear
          case '\r':
            matcher.appendReplacement(result, "\\\\r");
            break;
          case '\n':
            matcher.appendReplacement(result, "\\\\n");
            break;
          default:
            matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.format("\\\\u%04x", (int)c));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder(
    "import java.io.IOException;\n" +
    "import java.io.Writer;\n" +
    "import java.util.Map;\n" +
    "public class C implements Template {\n" +
    "    public void write(Writer out, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {\n"
);
```

Perhaps skip the `String` concatenation and use the `append()` methods too?

```
// 1024 size is an arbitrary choice, 
// the code below + example template stands at under 400 chars already
// each substitution will use an additional 60 bytes or so... 
// multiply accordingly for 4 fields, 
// and finally setting aside more spaces for the actual replacements
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder(1024);
script.append("import java.io.IOException;")
    .append("import java.io.Writer;")
    .append("import java.util.Map;")
    .append("public class C implements Template{")
    .append("public void write(Writer out,Map<String, String> params) throws IOException{");
```

Also,

```
result.append('"');
// instead of
result.append("\"");
```

Have you actually tested the speed of this, using something like say [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)? I'll also be interested to know how this compares with something written and compiled with Nashorn (on Java 8)...

Comment: `.append()` should be worse than `+`, since concatenation using `+` happens at compile time (Java compile time, not template compile time), whereas `.append()` happens at runtime.

Comment: JavaScript using Nashorn was much much worse than Java, by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @200_success ah ok...